# Get uid in list by searching child values firebase android

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63" : {
    "Age" : "20",
    "Full name" : "Mike",
    "Intent" : "Both",
    "Reward" : "Nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63.jpeg"
  },
  "fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2" : {
    "Age" : "19",
    "Full name" : "Other guy",
    "Intent" : "Looking for help",
    "Reward" : "nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2"
  }
}
```

This is my database. I want to get all the users with the same variablex. But i want only the id, the parent node. I want basically to build an array that contains all the ids of the users whose child value variablex is the same. And then use this array to call one user at a time get the id, perform other tasks with it etc.

```
public void othershit() {

    Query qname3 = mDatabase.child("Variablex").orderByChild("Variablex").equalTo(userinput);
    qname3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<>();
            List users = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
            textView8.setText(users.get(0).toString());
        }
```

This is trigered with a button but everytime it crashes. Also i have three users with the same variablex. The structure is the same, this is a bit outdated version of my database but it is essentially the same.

Comment: share your crash report.

Comment: If your `dataSnapshot.getKey()` returns you List then `users.getKey()` should return you `Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63`.

Comment: I cant run it on android studio, i am running it on a device and i cant get crash report. Also i need a list of all the ids that meet the query criteria, not just the first. So i can then get the second and third and so on.

Comment: @MikeKioulMikeKioulepoglou You say you want to get all the users with the same variablex, which is `one name`? Please responde with @.

Comment: Sorry, i mentioned it, that my actual firebase database has more users in the same structure with the same children just different values for each child and different ids each. Some of them have the same value in the child variablex. I want to get those. I just posted this piece of the database as a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

To retrieve the parent key of the found node which in your case is the FUID.

Edit -

Lets say your parent node for all the data is users

```
{
  "users" :{
"Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63" : {
    "Age" : "20",
    "Full name" : "Mike",
    "Intent" : "Both",
    "Reward" : "Nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63.jpeg"
  },
  "fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2" : {
    "Age" : "19",
    "Full name" : "Other guy",
    "Intent" : "Looking for help",
    "Reward" : "nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2"
  }
}
}
```

So here is what you need to do to get the list of all the ids which match the required

```
    List<String> userIds = new Arraylist<>();

        Query qname3 = mDatabase.child("users").child("Variablex").orderByChild("Variablex").equalTo(userinput)..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          userIds.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, but how do i get a list of all fuids that have equal variablex values? This will only give me the first. I need to get the second, then the third etc. One at a time. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason this only returns Variablex. Not even the value inside (one name). And i need the parent. Since all the users are children of root i am doing mDatabase.child("Variablex").orderbychild("Variablex").equalto(userinput); then i do userIds.add(datasnapshot.getKey()); and then display the result by textview.settext(userIds.get(0));

Comment: You need to first call child on the parent node
             Query qname3 = mDatabase.child("users").child("Variablex").orderByChild("Variablex").equalTo(userinput)..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()  
here users is the parent node as you can see so check out your parent node and do as I have said